# Xml file not found in xap

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, xna-4.0

I added a folder to my project and I added an **xml** file to the folder.
Set Build Action of file as **Resource**. Now try to load the file using line given below

XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("Xml/MyXML.xml");

The project compiles successfully but while running I get the below exception:

**Cannot find file 'WORDXML.xml' in the application xap package.**

Also, i checked the created XAP and not find anything related to folder.

Could anybody help me out where I am missing

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the build action to `Content`. Or otherwise you need to load it as a resource, with [Application.GetResourceStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190632%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)