# Cannot Find File in the Application XAP package

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am Trying to Read a XML file that is:

```
<root>
  <resources>
    <item>itemname1</item>
  </resources>
  <resources>
    <item>itemname2</item>
  </resources>
</root>
```

**C# code :**

```
        XDocument loadedData = XDocument.Load("items.xml");
        var data = from query in loadedData.Descendants("resources")
                   select new Item
                   {
                       item = (string)query.Element("item")
                   };
```

**When I place my XML file to Root Folder of Project its working fine** but if i place my file Under Any folder (e.g. /xmls/items.xml or /Assets/items.xml) its gets me Error that **Cannot Find File in the Application XAP package.** I have also edited xml file's Properties as Build Action -> Content and Copy To Output Dirtectoty -> Copy if newer. but same Result as cannot find file in the Application XAP Package.

I have also Refereed Question [Xml file not found in xap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091818/xml-file-not-found-in-xap)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code for loading XML file in folder

```
 StreamResourceInfo xml = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Assets/items.xml", UriKind.Relative));
        var appDataXml = XElement.Load(xml.Stream);
```

**Edit:** get item values

```
 var allItems = from o in appDataXml.Elements("resources")
                   select o;
        foreach (var item in allItems)
        { 
                var itemValue = item.Value;

        }
```

**Alternative solution for Not using ForEach :**

```
        var allItems = from o in appDataXml.Elements("resources")
                       select new Items
                       {
                           item = (string)o.Element("item")
                       };
        var Firstitem = allItems.Cast<Items>().ElementAt(0);
        MessageBox.Show(Firstitem.item.ToString());
```

Items Class Defination:

```
public class Items
{
    public string item { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: if i apply XDocument loadedData = appDataXml.Document its giving me object reference not set to an instance. Its already added

Comment: add following at the top


using System.Xml.Linq;

Comment: It works well but any other alternative for not using loop Because i Would have more than one xml and having all time loop would not Feasible for only accessing any element

Comment: Pretty well. Thanks alot